# docker-compose: Connect to mongodb using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm looking for some help on how I can connect to a mongodb using node in two different containers.

I have three services set up in my docker compose:

- webserver (irrelevant to question)
- nodeJs
- mongo database

The nodejs container is essentially an api which I can use to communicate with mongodb:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

app.post('/api/fetch-items', (req, res) => {
    if (req.headers.apikey !== process.env.API_KEY) return res.sendStatus(401)

    // URL is in the format: mongodb://user:pwd@database:27017
    MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, function(err, db) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        var dbo = db.db("db");
        dbo.collection("col").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            db.close();
            return res.status(200).send(result);
        });
    });
})

app.listen(4000)
```

This all works perfectly fine if I run node as a standalone container (not using docker-compose) and use localhost in the URL.

However, when I use the image in docker-compose I receive the response:

```
{
    "name": "MongoNetworkError"
}
```

when sending a request to the API.

I am currently using the hostname 'database' in the URL and this does not work. I have also tried using localhost.

There are also no errors as a result of the command `node server`.

If needed my Dockerfile for the node server is:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN chown node:node ./package*.json

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "node", "server" ]
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: database
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxx


  # Web server stuff

  node:
    image: created-node-server
    container_name: node
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
```

Finally, the output of docker network inspect:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "network_default",
        "Id": "3e51a90a23f2785cfc405243ad4c73991852f52826fd1cd0b14da5d4eaa180e4",
        "Created": "2021-01-12T01:07:42.656013002Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.23.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "418876a06c3f8fa430804ae77c66cca986a49dbc88374266346463f7f448baa7": {
                "Name": "database",
                "EndpointID": "ac08c5a439edd43e612723d269714e9dfbae29dbdb50790b61c66207287d70c8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7b6dcbb8f76618575c988a026ac0308075a116f79a2e58d8a146e33fb5d7674c": {
                "Name": "node",
                "EndpointID": "e6beb412a2fe97ae7d04d2484a7ca3634bfa37c82680becc412d1f44502da72f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f2ea250bccdb2c6a0c4d7818912ddbf29196eff072dad699e8dbcef466cd38a3": {
                "Name": "webserver",
                "EndpointID": "f6617aab4001032069e68300c5303fa730f3458e2fe0092ace45a9f67e16d7c5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "proj",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.4"
        }
    }
]
```

Essentially, I am retrieving the `MongoNetworkError` when trying to communicate with mongodb through node, both of which are docker containers created using docker-compose.

I hope all the above makes sense, sorry if it is a bit wordy, I have tried to include as much info as possible. Comment if you need any more info

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the full error message? `MongoNetworkError` is an error class, there should be a message like `failed to connect to server [address]` in the Node container's logs, which could be informative.

Comment: Where are you setting `$MONGODB_URL`, and to what value?

Comment: @ZacAnger The MongoNetworkError, is the full error returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include an environmental variable under the node service MONGODB_URL=mongodb://database:27017

Comment: i'm currently using a .env file, will that not work?

Comment: If you are using an env file from which you are expecting the container to consider the environmental variables then you have to defined it under the node service as  env_file: 
       - nameofthefile

Comment: I guess you must have used the .env file inside the source code but that .env file won't be loaded during the startup of the container instead you have to tell the container that you want to use the env file through the field I have mentioned above. [link] (https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) . You can get a reference from here.

Comment: This solved my issue thank, I also needed to create a new user as I wasn't using persistent storage

Comment: Glad to hear. :)